# RESTful routing to single firebase object from firebase array

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am confused on how to do a very, very trivial pattern with angular/firebase using angularfire.

Imagine you have a lil' old blog. You have some $scope.posts and you ng-repeat over them. Now you want to be able to click on one post and be routed to that post's page at '/posts/:id'. Since a $firebaseArray elements don't include their $id's **how do you pass a unique id of a single post to the url and onto the postsCtrl**?

`<a ng-repeat="post in posts href="/posts/{{??????}}">{{post.title}}</a>`

**Update**

The workaround I figured out is whenever I save a new post, I can save an attribute called "key" and then use this the way I would normally use the "id" attribute in every other framework.

`$firebaseArray(postsRef).$add($scope.post).then(function(ref) {
     ref.update({ key: ref.key()});
  });`

This hack, however, cannot be the solution to this simple, trivial, conventional pattern.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You're instincts are right, that hack isn't the answer. Instead use angular's built in (key, value) option for ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, post) in posts">
    <a ng-href="/posts/{{post.id}}">{{post.title}}</a>
</div>
```

Additional reference material on how to use AngularFire with ng1 can be observed in this [repo](https://github.com/BobbieBarker/chadtools/tree/master/src)

Comment: This pattern gives you the index, not the key of each post. I might be able to use this to create a ng-click function that took in the index, found the key from the $firebaseArray(), and then used that to change $location. Or I could just use parse.